# Python Relative Path - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

I need to pickle a python class I have instantiated and therefore need to use relative paths. I am using Python Version 3.6.6. Here is an example of how the project structure and code looks like:

```
modelling/
    test.py
    mod1/
        __init__.py
        classic_mod.py
```

**init**.py

```
from .classic_mod import classic
```

classic_mod.py

```
class classic:

    def __init__(self, input_string):
        self.input_string = input_string
        print(self.input_string)

    def log_info(self):
        print(self.input_string)
```

test.py

```
from .mod1 import classic_mod
from sklearn.externals import joblib

model = classic_mod.classic("Hello World!")
joblib.dump(model, "model.pkl")
```

If I use absolute paths I get problems when I load the pickle file into python in another folder. When I run test.py I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .mod1 import classic_mod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.mod1'; '__main__' is not a package
```

How can I solve this import error and at the same time pickle the class so I can use somewhere else?

Comment: Your class names should ideally start with a capital letter.

Comment: from .mod1 import classic_mod, mod1 is a module so this is inappropriate, use
from mod1 import classic_mod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap up your code in a package in order to use relative imports. Set a [setup script](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/setupscript.html) and use the `pip -e install` flag to install it as a development module. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) is a very good in-depth explanation of the problem you are facing.